# Do IOS UI elements need to be weak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, weak

When not using interface builder I always keep strong references to UI elements:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController 

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *folderLabel;
```

And then add them like this:

```
[self.view addSubview self.folderLabel];
```

where the initialiser is thus:

```
-(UILabel *)folderLabel{
    if(!_folderLabel) {
        _folderLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _folderLabel.text = @"foo";
    }
    return _folderLabel
}
```

I have been told that this is bad for some reason and they should always be weak..

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UILabel *folderLabel;

-(UILabel *)folderLabel{
    if(!_folderLabel) {
        UIlabel *folderLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        folderLabel.text = @"foo";
        [self.view addSubview:folderLabel];
        _folderLabel = folderLabel;
    }
    return _folderLabel
}
```

Is the strong reference a bad thing here?

Comment: Note that the higher voted answer rather than the accepted answer on that question is correct

Comment: that question refers to IBOulets, this is setting UI Elements programatically

Comment: the highest voted answer appears to be dated with new info about recommendations from apple about keeping them strong..

Comment: IBOutlet is just syntactic embellishment to allow the NIB binding process to find the property.  It doesn't matter how the element is created

Answer (score 0):

When you add the subview to self.view, it gets retained.  One pattern that works is to alloc the subview and store it in a local variable, add it to self.view then assign it to the ivar.

Comment: true, but the question is, is it a bad thing to have a strong reference in the header file, will it cause harm, retain cycles or memory leaks?

Comment: If you declare them as strong, you need to nil them out in viewDidUnload or it will leak.

Comment: @user3246173 No, they will be set to nil when the view controller is deallocated, which will remove the strong reference.

Comment: yes, that is true > ios 6.0

Comment: So post IOS 6 there is no need to declare them as weak and add view to subview within getters

Comment: There are long discussions on this elsewhere.  I should have marked it as a duplicate.